# connecting two separate ideas with "und" within a single dass-clause

Tags: word-order

Here is a sentence of my own making:

> Sie antwortet, **dass er von hier geradeaus gehen sollte und dann er die Bäckerei hinten rechts an der Schule sieht**.

Grammar checker begs to differ

> Sie antwortet, dass er von hier aus geradeaus gehen müsse, dann sehe er die Bäckerei hinten rechts an der Schule.

I'm curious if it's possible to connect two ideas with "und" within a single dass-clause.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the connection is possible, you just have to switch two words:

> Sie antwortet, dass er von hier geradeaus gehen sollte und [dass] **er**
> **dann** die Bäckerei hinten rechts an der Schule sieht.

The second *»dass«* is optional.

Comment: It's possible, just not good style, because the first part is Konjunktiv (*sollte* does not refer to a past tense here), and then the second part is indicative. The proposal by the grammar checker is good, it's just a somewhat elevated style. In plain: "Sie antwortet, dass er von hier geradeausgehen soll, und dass er dann ... sieht / sehen würde."

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this sentence:

First, "Sie antwortet ...". Everything after that is *indirekte Rede* (reported speech) and hence has to be in *Konjunktiv* (subjunctive mood). You did that in the first part, although correct would be *Präsens*, not *Präteritum*:

> [...] dass er von hier geradeaus gehen soll*te* (solle!)

but not in the second part:

> [...] an der Schule *sieht* (sehe!).

The grammar checker is wrong about replacing "sollen" with "müssen". Yes, "müssen" is possible, but "sollen" is too. "Müssen" stresses the fact that you have to go to A to experience B. "Sollen" is suggesting that you go to A, then you will eventually experience B.

The next problem with your sentence is: "und" as a *Konjunktion* connects main sentences, e.g.:

> [Er kommt nach Hause] und [seine Katze begrüßt ihn].

Notice the placement of the *Verb* in both parts: it is in seond place, because German is a V2-language. In your case the *Verb* is in last position in your second sentence and this is only the case with a *Relativsatz*. But a *Relativsatz doesn't need to be connected with "und". e.g.:

> [Er kommt nach Hause], [wo ihn seine Katze begrüßt].

The second part is just a detailed explanation what "nach Hause" means and because it is not a main sentence any more the *Verb* goes last. Hence:

> dann er die Bäckerei hinten rechts an der Schule sieht.

is plain wrong word order. Either you create a real dependent clause:

> ...gehen solle, von wo [aus] er die Bäckerei hinten rechts an der Schule sehe.

or you create a main sentence, but then the *Verb* goes second:

> Sie **antwortet**, (*Hauptsatz*, *Verb* second)
> dass er von hier geradeaus gehen **solle** (*Relativsatz*, *Verb* last)
> und
> dann **sehe** er die Bäckerei hinten rechts an der Schule. (*Hauptsatz*, *Verb* second)

As you can see you do NOT connect anything "within a single dass-clause", but you connect two sentences, one consisting of a main sentence and a dependent clause and a second main sentence.

Also, the "und" is not really necessary - a simple comma would suffice.

Comment: I disagree that Konjunktiv is mandatory in reported speech. Using Indikativ is also possible and common practice, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirekte_Rede#Modus

Comment: But it is true that "solle" is better than "sollte" and that you would not switch from Konjunktiv to Indikativ in the same embedded clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can write ".... und er dann die Bäckerei sehe" (conjunctive). In this case the "dass" is implicit.

You can also make the "dass" explicit:

"... und dass er dann die Bäckerei sehe".

However, the first subordinate sentence unnecessarily uses conjunctive 2, so to be consistent, you would use "sähe" or "sehen würde"; or you use conjunctive 1 in both cases. I don't see a convincing point in having conj 2 here.

Comment: If *Konjunktiv Präsens* ("Konjunktiv I") or *Irrealis* ("Konjunktiv II") is used depends on the stance of the speaker towards the statement in the reported speech. See: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75110/indirect-speech/75147#75147 (with examples)

Comment: @bakunin : Correct. But in many cases people use conjunctive 2 throughout for simplicity. Another (legal) reason for C2 in reported speech would be the the case, where the verb form of C1 would look identical to indicative. While this does not apply in our example here, I think it is one cause why people then start using C2 from the onset :  They don't have to think whether or not C1 would look like indicative.