# Gebaut (werden) würde

Tags: colloquial

Was ist richtig? Ist das *werden* unnötig?

> Wenn rund ums Grundstück ein Zaun **gebaut würde**, wären wir alle in Sicherheit.
> Wenn rund ums Grundstück ein Zaun **gebaut werden würde**, wären wir alle in Sicherheit.

> Was du gerade gesagt hast, **würde** von meinen Freunden als komisch angesehen.
> Was du gerade gesagt hast, **würde** von meinen Freunden als komisch angesehen **werden**.

Comment: An die Closevoter: Eine Möglichkeit  ist, dass die Frage nur deshalb so kurz ist, weil sich der Fragesteller eine präzisere Frage weder auf Deutsch noch auf Englisch zutraut. Zwei Beispielsätze werden genannt, das schließt "proofreading request" m.E. schon aus.

Answer (score 6):

Ja, das zusätzliche "werden" ist in beiden Beispielen unnötig, kann aber eingesetzt werden.

Die Erklärung dafür ist, dass "würde" und "werden würde" zwei verschiedene Konjunktivformen von "werden" sind.

Du kennst es sicher von anderen Verben, dass man entweder die "starke" Konjunktiv-II-Form oder, weniger formell, den vereinfachten Konjunktiv II mit "würde" und dem Infinitiv benutzen kann:

> Sie wünschte, er **ginge** öfter mit ihr tanzen.
> Sie wünschte, er **würde** öfter mit ihr tanzen **gehen**.

Der "starke" Konjunktiv II von *werde* ist aber nun zufällig auch *würde*, darum sehen diese Varianten da so aus:

> Er wünschte, es **würde** ein Zaun gebaut.
> Er wünschte, es **würde** ein Zaun gebaut **werden**.

Answer (score 3):

Es handelt sich um unterschiedliche Zeitformen.

*Wenn ... gebaut würde* ist Präsens Passiv Konjunktiv II.

*Wenn... gebaut werden würde* ist Futur Passiv Konjunktiv II.

Da in beiden Fällen auf eine hypothetische Zukunft geblickt wird, ist das Futur nicht nötig, weil der Konjunktiv II allein ausreicht. Es ist aber auch nicht falsch.

Answer (score 1):

> … würde. — Konjunktiv II
>
> … werden würde. — Futur I Konjunktiv II

Dieses *Futur I Konjunktiv II* ist eine Ersatzform für den Konjunktiv II. Beide bedeuten genau dasselbe. Man benötigt sie allerdings nur bei Verben, bei denen die Konjunktiv-II-Form nicht von der Präteritum-Form unterscheidbar ist:

> …, dass man einen Zaun baute. — Konjunktiv II oder Präteritum
>
> …, dass man einen Zaun bauen würde. — Futur I Konjunktiv II

Answer (score 0):

Zunächst das Grundsätzliche: beide von Dir angeführten Beispiele sind Passiv-Kontruktionen. Die Grundformen lauten jeweils:

> Der Zaun wird gebaut.
> Das wird (an-)gesehen.

Da die Sätze überdies im Konjunktiv stehen, muß auch der Konjunktiv von "werden" verwendet werden:

> Der Zaun würde gebaut.
> Das würde (an-)gesehen.

Tatsächlich aber stehen die Sätze nicht im Präsens, sondern im Futur. Deshalb tritt ein weiteres "werden" hinzu ("ich baue - ich werde bauen"):

> Der Zaun würde gebaut werden.
> Das würde (an-)gesehen werden.

Der Unterschied zwischen Deinen Sätzen ist also jeweils, daß der eine im Präsens, der andere im Futur steht.
Die Bedeutung ist in beiden Fällen dieselbe: eine Möglichkeit, die aber - zur Zeit, also im Präsens - nicht verwirklicht wird. Im ersten Beispiel etwa :

> Wenn rund ums Grundstück ein Zaun gebaut (werden) würde, wären wir alle in Sicherheit.

wird eine hypothetische Möglichkeit - ein Zaun wird gebaut - vorgestellt, aber auch gesagt, daß *derzeit* diese Möglichkeit nicht umgesetzt wird. Natürlich gelten die Konsequenzen - wir sind in Sicherheit - auch für den Fall, daß die Hypothese - der Zaunbau - irgendwann in Zukunft in die Tat umgesetzt wird. Mit anderen Worten: wenn wir den Zaun jetzt bauen, hat das dieselben Folgen, wie wenn wir ihn später bauen.

Es gibt in der deutschen Sprache zwar zu den meisten Zeitformen im Indikativ auch entsprechende Formen des Konjunktivs, aber deren temporale Bedeutung ist unterschiedlich zu jener des Indikativs. Siehe eine etwas ausführlichere Behandlung etwa [hier, allerdings in Englisch](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75110/indirect-speech/75147#75147).